# How to remove a trailing slash from one or two directories from URL in .htaccess / mod redirect?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following URLs:

```
example.com/test/
example.com/test/mode/
```

that needs to be automatically converted to:

```
example.com/test
example.com/test/mode
```

Basically, I want the trailing slash to be removed.

My existing .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rule to handle example.com/xyz/mode
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1&mode=$2 [L,QSA]

# Rule to handle example.com/xyz
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule **on top** to remove trailing slash:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: This is working. Thank you! You seem to be very good in .htaccess redirects :)